# MY Gnome-Shell Crashed while resizing dock Icon size or while I want to show Hidden files Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, mouse, crash

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I've upgraded from 18.04 LTS. When I resized the Dock icon I saw my gnome-shell crashed and my mouse cursor is not moving.Same thing happened When I wanted to show my hidden files and now when taking mouse in the dock it shows the loading icon. What can I do?
Note: My **dock** is in the bottom and **show application** icon is in the left corner.

partho@Partho:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 16

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 partho partho 4096 Jun 15 20:47 .
drwx------ 4 partho partho 4096 Jun 16 22:37 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 partho partho 4096 Jun 15 19:35 adjust.brightness.icon@orschiro.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 partho partho 4096 Jun 15 20:47 soft-brightness@fifi.org
```

partho@Partho:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 15 01:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 15 01:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 15 01:55 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 15 01:50 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 15 01:52 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

partho@Partho:~$ free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.1Gi       4.0Gi       290Mi       1.5Gi       5.0Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi
```

partho@Partho:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness**
vm.swappiness = 60

```
partho@Partho:~$ ls -al /var/crash
total 84272
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie     4096 Jun 16 21:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root   root         4096 Aug  6  2019 ..
-rw-r-----  1 partho whoopsie 42455672 Jun 16 21:47 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 partho whoopsie        0 Jun 16 21:47 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 partho whoopsie 43553172 Jun 16 16:09 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 partho whoopsie        0 Jun 15 03:14 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 partho whoopsie   270063 Jun 15 03:16 _usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 partho whoopsie        0 Jun 15 03:16 _usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1000.upload
partho@Partho:~$ top

top - 01:06:05 up  1:10,  1 user,  load average: 0.63, 0.67, 0.69
Tasks: 255 total,   2 running, 253 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.6 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.6 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7848.7 total,   4367.2 free,   1765.9 used,   1715.5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  15625.0 total,  15625.0 free,      0.0 used.   5583.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                              
   2195 partho    20   0 4145112 247732  88996 R   8.6   3.1   7:09.97 gnome-shell                                                          
   1967 partho    20   0  805044  59508  40540 S   4.0   0.7   2:55.32 Xorg                                                                 
   5963 partho    20   0  882348  48040  36928 S   1.7   0.6   0:01.75 gnome-terminal-                                                      
      1 root      20   0  168032  11972   8460 S   0.7   0.1   0:05.54 systemd                                                              
    266 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:02.57 kworker/u8:6-events_power_efficient                                  
   2665 partho    20   0  942988 328324 134800 S   0.3   4.1   2:35.87 chrome                                                               
   5799 partho    20   0 4713356 192860  97576 S   0.3   2.4   0:08.31 chrome                                                               
   5997 partho    20   0   12560   4240   3380 R   0.3   0.1   0:00.23 top                                                                  
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                             
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                               
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                           
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                         
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                         
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.17 ksoftirqd/0                                                          
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:05.06 rcu_sched                                                            
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 migration/0                                                          
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                        
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                              
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                              
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                        
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.13 migration/1                                                          
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.13 ksoftirqd/1                                                          
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd                                                 
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                                              
     22 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2                                                        
     23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.12 migration/2                                                          
     24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.13 ksoftirqd/2                                                          
     26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kblockd                                                 
     27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3                                                              
     28 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3                                                        
     29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.12 migration/3                                                          
     30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.21 ksoftirqd/3                                                          
     32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-kblockd                                                 
     33 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                            
     34 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                
     35 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_kthre                                                      
     36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kauditd                                                              
     38 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                                           
     39 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 oom_reaper                                                           
     40 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 writeback                                                            
     41 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kcompactd0                                                           
     42 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 ksmd                                                                 
     43 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khugepaged                                                           
partho@Partho:~$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=f840c88c-9b5c-406b-a600-fae7d126de3d none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`partho@Partho:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version F1`

Comment: Please one concise question at one time on this site. So please delete the part about "system monitor". Provide specific detail on how you proceed to allow other people to reproduce the issue. Use "edit" to update your question.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have given the info that you asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Your swap is excessive, but that's not your problem. The rest looks ok. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `top` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema Updated.

Comment: Yes, you are having quite a problem with crashes. Do two things for me... at least temporarily... go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable ALL extensions and restart GNOME Shell with alt+f2 then r then enter, and use Firefox instead of Chrome. I need to see if one of them is causing your problem. Have you ever run memory tests on this computer?

Comment: Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model of your computer.

Comment: @heynnema Post Updated.  Q: Have you ever run memory tests on this computer? A: Yes I have ran benchmark test about read and write speed.

Comment: You forgot to tell me exactly what make/model # of your computer. I need that to be able to check for a newer BIOS. Memory benchmark tests are not diagnostic memory tests. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.